# Re-importing live EE2 Playa/Matrix data into local EE3 upgrade using native Grid/Relationship fields

Tags: matrix, playa, relationships, grid, ee2-upgrades

I’m currently updating an EE2 to EE3 which has a lot of playa / matrix custom fields. On my local ee2 dev site I am about to run the Playa/Matrix importer addon to get duplicate field data into the native grid/relationship fields. However my problem is that eventually I will have to get the current live site EE2 data re-imported into the upgraded ee3 site before going live, but I need to somehow get the current live ee2 playa/matrix data into the new ee3 native grid/relationship fields. I am aware of using the DataGrab addon for importing purposes, but not sure how to accomplish this field data transfer (ie. Playa/Matrix field data into new Grid/Relationship fields?

Does anyone have any suggestions or previous experience with this?

Many thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

ElisLab has a plugin to do this job. https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/playa-matrix-importer

Comment: Hi @mufi - Many thanks for the response. Yes I mentioned the importer in the question above. It's a question of getting the playa/matrix data imported into the native relationship/grid fields within an ee3 upgrade.